# How to define server root for inets tftp server

Tags: erlang, inets, tftp

Seems trivial, but property {server_root, Path} in server config doesn't work. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

it [appears](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2006-October/023226.html) you need to set it in the tftp_file [callback](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/tftp.html#write_file-3)

```
tftp:start([{callback, {".*", tftp_file, [{root_dir, "/tftpboot"}]}}]).
```